# How do you type the caret (^) character with the Azerty amélioré new French keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

In the new official (2019) Azerty amélioré French keyboard layout (https://norme-azerty.fr), how do you type the caret character (^)? The <kbd>^</kbd> key (next to the backspace) is a circonflex dead key that types the circonflex (^) on top of characters, such as â or ĝ. It is not a standalone caret (^).

In the old Azerty layout, you could get a caret by typing the circonflex dead key twice and then get two carets (^^); then you could simply delete one, and then you get your single caret. But in the Azerty amélioré layout, if you type the dead key twice, instead of giving two circonflexes, it gives a caret with a circonflex: ̂̂. In some contexts, this looks like two carets, of which you can delete one to get just one caret, but it cannot fool other contexts. Most notably, I recently tried to do the exponent in a formula in Google Sheets and I get an error whenever I try the double-dead-key trick. Programmatically, it is recognized as a circonflex, not as a caret, so it does not work.

So, **how do you type the caret (^) character with the Azerty amélioré new French keyboard layout?**

Comment: If you're using Windows10, I'd add the old layout to your languages. Then shift between the two using `Windows + Spacebar`. Only takes a second once you're used to switching between layouts.

Answer (score 1):

To get a true caret, you type <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>[space]</kbd>, that is, the circonflex dead key first and then the space bar. This gives ^. You can also do <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>[space]</kbd> (press both keys at the same time) for the same result.